# Checking whether RabbitMQ cluster is idle or not

Tags: rabbitmq

I have got a task to check whether created RabbitMQ cluster is idle(has been used) or not. I can think of only one case which is non existence of queues and exchanges. If no queues are created then we can easily say that the created cluster has not been used. But my task is to collect all such cases by which we can check if created cluster is idle or been used.So I want everyone to help me to get more cases or situations where a RabbitMQ cluster will not be active for some time  and be idle.

Comment: Maybe we should start by clarifying what you mean by idle a bit more?
If you have connections established, but no action taken (no message in or out, no config change), does it count as a idle cluster, or not?

Comment: Yes, If the connection established but no action is taken then also the cluster is in idle state. Idle in my case is not being used at least for 15 days. If no connection established in the cluster not even for once then we can easily say that cluster is not even used once for any message transfer so that cluster is definitely an idle cluster.

Comment: Hello @Olivier , Is it possible to get the message count of whole RabbitMQ cluster. I just know how get the message count of a particular queue. I have many queues in the cluster .I thought of  looking at message count by which we can check whether cluster is idle or active. So please let me know if you have any answer.Along with that if you have any ideas for checking whether cluster is in idle state or not , Please help me .

Comment: Hi Priya,
To check the total messages count is actually quite easy, you can find the information from the admin api `/api/overview` endpoint, in there you can check the queue_totals. Regarding the global question, it's actually a bit harder, Only way I can think of is to increase the logging so that you can trace all the activity, including config, and . Still idle notion is based on timing, so which period needs to be covered? Even in this context, the admin api might be a good place to start as it can be requested to provide statistics on a given period.

Comment: @Olivier Thank you for clearing my doubts. I just wanted to know any way to get to know about connection activity, How to check whether established connection is being active or not?

Answer (score 0):

Because of RabbitMQ's behavior, a cluster that is currently not being used (but once was) looks exactly the same as one that has never been used (which is a good thing for performance).

Assuming no client deletes the queue it is using, or the cluster creation involves creating new queues or exchanges, then checking if there are any existing queues (or any non-default exchanges) is your best bet at **guessing** if any client has ever used a RabbitMQ cluster.

Comment: Yes what you are saying is correct . But I need some more cases by which I can check if cluster is idle or not. Even if the queue created has some messages but by some issues the cluster can be in idle state . I wanted to know that. I have to write a python script where all conditions by which we can tell whether  RabbitMQ cluster is idle or not should be mentioned. So I am seeking for everyone's help as I am not able to find anything more, other than non existence of exchanges  and queues.